# Getting Django and PostgreSQL to work

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to get Django and PostgreSQL to work.

So far I am getting the following error when I run `syncdb`.

```
....
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

The following is my `settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mydb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'username',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'pwd123',                # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                 # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I think I have installed psycopg2 correctly, but I am not sure (through MacPorts).

Is there a way whether I can check whether psycopg2 is installed?

[This link contains the install log of psycopg2](http://codepaste.net/hpyhjp)

**UPDATE**

I got it working with the method below, but how do I check whether psycopg2 was actually installed before? and if so how to remove it completely?

Comment: I've had no luck using MacPorts for Django development, it never seems to install the right versions or in a compatible.  Use easyinstall as Pablo suggests.  Also, I use virtualenv and don't I don't touch the base python install which helps a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MAC, make sure `psycopg2` is installed and accesible to your main python interpreter.

This is how I'd install it on a mac:

```
$ sudo easy_install django
$ sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

Then test it:

```
$ python
>>> import django
>>> import psycopg2
```

You should not get any errors.

Also, if you are using an Eclipse/PYDEV, make sure you reconfigure your interpreter **after** installing django and psycopg2 libraries.

Comment: I've got django smooth and running and im using pycharm, it has been running great and I am only having problems with psycopg2. Is there a way to uninstall the current psycopg2 that I have? and install with easy_install instead?

Comment: Just try the easy_install anyway. I think psycopg2 needs postgresql libraries to compile, so you might as well try installing postgresql client libraries. I have mine installed from EnterpriseDB installer.